# How to write pyspark groupby agg function that does string comparison

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I'm trying to compare two very large CSVs record by record, and I need to generate a summary matrix to show if for the same record id whether if each field changed.
my data looks like below:

```
    record_id, colA, colB ....file
    10086 , 'haha', 'ok'  ....'csv1'
    10086 , 'haha', 'oh no' ....'csv2'
    10087, 'ok', 'good' ........'csv1'
    10087, 'ok', 'good' ........'csv2’
```

and I need to get a dataframe looks like below:

```
    record_id, colA, colB ....file
    10086 , 1, 0  ….0
    10087, 1, 1 ……..0
```

the idea is that I want to load the two csv into dataframes, create union and get df_both that contains double entries of records from both csvs. now I just need to call

```
    df_both.groupBy("record_id").agg(string_comparison('colA'), string_comparison('colB') ...).show()
```

to generate a boolean matrix.

I just need to figure out how to write the string_comparison aggregation function that checks two rows with the same record_id by each fields, then returns a row that's like "record_id, 0, 1, 0, 1 ...."

this is doable using RDD, but python with spark dataframe with way faster than RDD, is there anyway I can achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to rename the columns so you can differentiate them once you perform the join.
After first join I'm expecting to get output like this

```
record_id COLA    COLB  colA    colB
10086     haha    ok    haha    oh no
10087     ok      good  ok      good
```

then you can compare two columns and can get the required output.

```
@udf
def compareCols(col1,col2):
    if col1==col2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
outputDF = AboveDF.withColumn('compareA', compareCols(col('COLA'),col('colA'))\
                  .withColumn('compareB', compareCols(col('COLB'),col('colB'))
```